# how to make my angular2 app functions work asynchronize

Tags: angular

I have an ng2 app that should read json file , then use the result to write file data to websql db .

in app.compopnent.ts constructor I create DatabaseService :

```
constructor(private dbservice : DatabaseService )
```

in the DatabaseService  constructor I need to check if websql db is up to date with my json file , and in case it isn't I update websql  db.

here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,  Headers,RequestOptions, Response  } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


import "reflect-metadata";
import {ConnectionOptions, createConnection ,Connection} from "typeorm";
import {Post } from "./entity/Post";
import {DbMetadata} from "./entity/DbMetadata";

@Injectable()
export class  DatabaseService {

private options: ConnectionOptions;
private connection: Promise<Connection>;

private MDataFileVersion : string ;
private MPLanguageFileVersion : string ;


 constructor(private http: Http)
 {
    this.options =  
    {
      driver: 
      {
        type: "websql",
        database: "test",
        extra: {
            version: 1,
            description: "test database",
            size: 2 * 1024 * 1024
          }
      },
      autoSchemaSync: true ,
      entities: [ Post , DbMetadata] // here we load all entities from entity directory]
    }; 

  this.connection  = createConnection(this.options);

  this.setVersionFile ( this.MDataFileVersion ,"./data/db/materialData.json");
  this.setVersionFile ( this.MPLanguageFileVersion ,"./data/db/MaterialsPerLanguage.json");

  console.log("DatabaseService : constructor finish..."  );
 }


 private setVersionFile( resultAttribute : string  ,fileName : string ) 
{
  this.http.get(fileName)
      .map(resp => resp.json())
      .subscribe(
        success => 
        {
          if(success) 
          {
              console.log(success);
              resultAttribute = success.version;
              console.log("resp.version = "+success.version);
          }
          else
          {
            console.log(" read db file error "+ fileName);
          }  
        },
        error => 
        {
          console.log(" read db file error "+ fileName + " error = "+error);
        }
  );
 }...
```

and in app.compopnent.ts constructor I call

```
console.log("ngOnInit dbservice. "+this.dbservice.MDataFileVersion);
```

before I start connecting to DB ,

The problem is dbservice.MDataFileVersion is not ready with the value .

how can I sync this ?

Answer (score 0):

In your app component, you should subscribe to the observable in the DB service and then get/set/use its data.

DBService:

```
...    
public getVersion() {
    this.http.get(fileName)
          .map(resp => resp.json());
    }
```

App component:

```
...{
this.dbService.getVersion().subscribe( response=> {
  console.log(response.version);
...
}
```